# Why do I receive the error 'count must be integer multiple of packet size' when using USB1408FS?

Tags: matlab, mcc

When using USB-1408FS I get the following error:

> count must be integer multiple of packet size for continuous mode.

I know that the packet size is 32 and the count must be a multiple of that. The code only works when the number of repeats (in this code it is 5) is under 7. When I put number 8 on (which makes 32) it gives me that error. And anything above 8 does not work.

```
nchannel=1;
AO=analogoutput('mcc',0);
set(AO,'BufferingMode','manual');
set(AO,'BufferingConfig',[128 2]);
addchannel(AO, [0:nchannel-1]);
samplerate=500;
sampleinterval=1/samplerate;
set(AO,'SampleRate',samplerate);
set(AO, 'TriggerType','Manual');
ActualRate=get(AO,'SampleRate');

%%set up desired output vector
V4 = 4
outputvector = repmat([0;1;1;0],5,1)*V


%%Load device memory  
putdata(AO,outputvector);
start(AO);

%%trigger output
trigger(AO)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to generate the error.

Comment: I have edited the post and added all of the code. Thank you.